# How to properly index MongoDB queries with multiple $and and $or statements

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in MongoDB (app_logins) that hold documents with the following structure:

```
{
   "_id"   : "c8535f1bd2404589be419d0123a569de"
   "app"   : "MyAppName",
   "start" : ISODate("2014-02-26T14:00:03.754Z"),
   "end"   : ISODate("2014-02-26T15:11:45.558Z")
}
```

Since the documentation says that the queries in an $or can be executed in parallel and can use separate indices, and I assume the same holds true for $and, I added the following indices:

```
db.app_logins.ensureIndex({app:1})
db.app_logins.ensureIndex({start:1})
db.app_logins.ensureIndex({end:1})
```

But when I do a query like this, way too many documents are scanned:

```
db.app_logins.find(
{
   $and:[
      { app : "MyAppName" },
      {
        $or:[
          {
             $and:[
                { start : { $gte:new Date(1393425621000) }},
                { start : { $lte:new Date(1393425639875) }}
             ]
          },
          {
             $and:[
                { end   : { $gte:new Date(1393425621000) }},
                { end   : { $lte:new Date(1393425639875) }}
             ]
          },
          {
             $and:[
                { start : { $lte:new Date(1393425639875) }},
                { end   : { $gte:new Date(1393425621000) }}
             ]
          }
        ]
      }
   ]
}
).explain()

{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor app_1",
    "isMultiKey" : true,
    "n" : 138,
    "nscannedObjects" : 10716598,
    "nscanned" : 10716598,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 10716598,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 10716598,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 30658,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 38330,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "app" : [
            [
                "MyAppName",
                "MyAppName"
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "127.0.0.1:27017"
}
```

I know that this can be caused because 10716598 match the 'app' field, but the other query can return a much smaller subset.

Is there any way I can optimize this? The aggregation framework comes to mind, but I was thinking that there may be a better way to optimize this, possibly using indexes.

**Edit:**

Looks like if I add an index on app-start-end, as Josh suggested, I am getting better results. I am not sure if I can optimize this further this way, but the results are much better:

```
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor app_1_start_1_end_1",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 138,
    "nscannedObjects" : 138,
    "nscanned" : 8279154,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 138,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 8279154,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 2934,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 13539,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "app" : [
            [
                "MyAppName",
                "MyAppName"
            ]
        ],
        "start" : [
            [
                {
                    "$minElement" : 1
                },
                {
                    "$maxElement" : 1
                }
            ]
        ],
        "end" : [
            [
                {
                    "$minElement" : 1
                },
                {
                    "$maxElement" : 1
                }
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "127.0.0.1:27017"
}
```

Comment: Try `.ensureIndex({app:1, start:1, end:1})`

Comment: I added the result of the query using that index. The nscanned went down for about 2M. I am not sure if I can get it down any further...

Comment: I'll move my comment to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [compound index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-compound/) to further improve performance.

Try using `.ensureIndex({app:1, start:1, end:1})`

This will allow mongo to match on `app` using an index, and then within the documents that matched on `app`, it will match on `start` also using an index. Likewise, for the documents that matched on `start` within the documents it matched on `app`, it will match on `end` using an index.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt $and is executed in parallel.  I haven't seen any documentation suggest so either.  It just logically doesn't make sense as $and needs both to be present.  Opposed to $or, only 1 needs to exist.
Your example only uses "start" & "end" without "app".  I would drop "app" in the complex index which should reduce the index size.   It will reduce the chance of RAM swapping if your database grows too big.
If searching for "app" is separate from "start" & "end", then have a separate simple index on "app" only, plus the complex index of "start" & "end" will be more efficient.